# Background worker doesn't work at second time

Tags: .net, vb.net, background, crash, worker

i have a very strange problem with Background Workers in VB.NET... I'm using two background workers (bw1 and bw2) in order to do two diferent tasks... the only reason I use Background Worker is showing progress report in a progress bar control.

Everything works fine... the problem is when I try to use bw1 again after use bw1 and bw2.. the program crashes... it doesn't say any error message... just crashes and not responding...

```
Private Sub btnTimbra_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTimbra.Click
    cargaCert()
    cargaDatos()
    cargaEmisor()
    cargaPAC()

    strXML = cXML()
    xml = xmlSellado()
    strguid = Guid.NewGuid.ToString("N")

    'Relevant code**********
    If bw1.IsBusy <> True Then
        bw1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
    '*************************
End Sub
```

DoWork Method from Bw1 is:

```
Private Sub bw1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw1.DoWork
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    If worker.CancellationPending = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        Timbrar(strNombreArchivo, cfdi.Emisor.rfc, cfdi.Receptor.rfc, strguid)
    End If
End Sub
```

If I restart the Application works very well... what am I doing wrong with Background Worker??

Thank you!!!

Comment: There is nothing here that will let anyone to answer your question. The only tip I can give you - un-wire and dispose your worker at the end of work. And for each new job, create and wire new worker. This way you will guaranty that it will work.

Comment: A crash is just an unhandled exception. That exception is there to tell you what happened.  Look at it.